# Do two verbs mean there are two clauses in a sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction, clauses

I'd like to ask whether the direct object in this sentence is a non-finite clause and thus the sentence is not a simple sentence?

> Gatsby doesn't want to have any trouble with anybody.

I'd analyze it like this:

- Gatsby (subject)
- doesn't want (predicator)
- to have any trouble with anybody (direct object)

Is that **to have any trouble with anybody** a non-finite clause or just a verb phrase?

Comment: I count three verbs "doesn't", "want" and "have"

Answer (score 1):

*to have any trouble with anybody* is both a verb phrase and a non-finite clause.

Within the main clause, the whole phrase is a verb phrase with the function of *direct object*, just as you analysed it.

On its own level (non-finite clause) you could analyze it like so:

> - *to have*: predicate
> - *any trouble*: object
> - *with anybody*: prepositional object

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo :P I edited my post